# Dynamic programming with large inputs

Tags: java, algorithm, knapsack-problem

I am trying to solve a classic Knapsack problem with huge capacity of 30.000.000 and it works well up until 20.000.000 but then it runs out of memory:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I have tried to divide all values and capacity by 1.000.000 but that generates floats and I don't think that is the correct approach. I have also tried to make the arrays and matrix of type long but that does not help.
Perhaps another data-structure?
Any pointers welcome...

Code:

```
public class Knapsack {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);   // number of items
         int W = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);   // maximum weight of knapsack
```

`int[] profit = new int[N+1];
    int[] weight = new int[N+1];

    // generate random instance, items 1..N
    for (int n = 1; n <= N; n++) {
        profit[n] = (int) (Math.random() * 1000000);
        weight[n] = (int) (Math.random() * W);
    }

    // opt[n][w] = max profit of packing items 1..n with weight limit w
    // sol[n][w] = does opt solution to pack items 1..n with weight limit w include item n?
    int[][] opt = new int[N+1][W+1];
    boolean[][] sol = new boolean[N+1][W+1];

    for (int n = 1; n <= N; n++) {
        for (int w = 1; w <= W; w++) {

            // don't take item n
            int option1 = opt[n-1][w];

            // take item n
            int option2 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            if (weight[n] <= w) option2 = profit[n] + opt[n-1][w-weight[n]];

            // select better of two options
            opt[n][w] = Math.max(option1, option2);
            sol[n][w] = (option2 > option1);
        }
    }

    // determine which items to take
    boolean[] take = new boolean[N+1];
    for (int n = N, w = W; n > 0; n--) {
        if (sol[n][w]) { take[n] = true;  w = w - weight[n]; }
        else           { take[n] = false;                    }
    }

    // print results
    System.out.println("item" + "\t" + "profit" + "\t" + "weight" + "\t" + "take");
    for (int n = 1; n <= N; n++) {
        System.out.println(n + "\t" + profit[n] + "\t" + weight[n] + "\t" + take[n]);
    }
    //Copyright © 2000–2011, Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne. Last updated: Wed Feb 9       //09:20:16 EST 2011.
}`

Comment: Have you tried increasing the heap size with -X:MaxPermGen=512m?

Comment: @ChrisChambers Considering error message it's not lack of PermGen space. If increasing anything then use -Xmx option, like for example -Xmx2048m

Comment: As suggested by Keyser, you only need the value of opt[n-1][] to calculate opt[n]. Hence you can do with a 1D array and overwrite it.

Comment: I have tried now with -Xmx2g and it works however I am unsure if this is the correct approach.

Comment: I tried to use above program. But it gave an error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0. What can I do for solve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Here are a couple of tricks I've used for things like that that.

First, a variant of a sparse matrix. It's not really sparse, but instead of assuming that "non-stored entries" are zero, you assume they're the same as the entry before. This can work in either direction (in the direction of the capacity or in the direction of the items), afaik not (easily) in both directions at the same time. Good trick, but doesn't defeat instances that are huge in both directions.

Secondly, a combination of Dynamic Programming and Branch & Bound. First, use DP with only the "last two rows". That gives you the value of the optimal solution. Then use Branch & Bound to find the subset of items that corresponds to the optimal solution. Sort by `value/weight`, apply the relaxation `value[next_item] * (capacity_left / weight[next_item])` to bound with. Knowing the optimal value ahead of time makes pruning very effective.

The "last two rows" refers to the "previous row" (a slice of the tableau that has the solutions for all items up to `i`) and the "current row" (that you're filling right now). it could look something like this, for example: (this is C# btw, but should be easy to port)

```
int[] row0 = new int[capacity + 1], row1 = new int[capacity + 1];
for (int i = 0; i < weights.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < row1.Length; j++)
    {
        int value_without_this_item = row1[j];
        if (j >= weights[i])
            row0[j] = Math.Max(value_without_this_item,
                               row1[j - weights[i]] + values[i]);
        else
            row0[j] = value_without_this_item;
    }
    // swap rows
    int[] t = row1;
    row1 = row0;
    row0 = t;
}

int optimal_value = row1[capacity];
```

Comment: Thanks Harlod, my head really spins now. Didn't quiet get that. So I should start bottom up with DP to get the most optimal value?

Comment: @jasonD yes, that's the idea

Comment: but don't you need the calculations from the row above? If I have e.g. 7 items and start at item 5 instead of 1 it does not come to the correct answer.

Comment: I hope it's clear now. Of course, after the DP phase, you still have to do B&B to figure out the actual solution.

Comment: I have implemented it now but it still fails to give correct answer when you run with large inputs > 20.000.000 for capacity and =<10.000.000 for weights. For smaller inputs it works.

Comment: @jasonD well, everything breaks eventually, but I expected it to get further. What goes wrong?

Comment: @Chaffers it uses a lot less - just two rows instead of as many rows as you have items, unless you mean the first trick, in that case, absolutely (but it *usually* helps).

Comment: @harold it seems that it reaches a max profit of 2800 when it should be around 30000.

Comment: @jasonD that's odd, it worked on my test instances, can I borrow your test case?

Comment: @harold capacity 32356000 , weight-value pairs (2000000,200),(3500000,400),(2300000,210),(8000000,730), (10000000,1000),(1500000,160),(1000000,100)

Comment: @jasonD ok well this is supposed to be 0/1 knapsack right? That's what your code did at any rate. 2800 corresponds to taking all the items, can't get more than that with 0/1 knapsack. By the way, you can divide weights and the capacity by their GCD, saves a ton of time.

Comment: Aha ok, so it needs to be the unbounded algorithm I guess... I think I get it now...Thanks harold!

Comment: @Harold His problem however isn't the inefficiency of the code but the fact this it uses too much heap space. Using less but maintaining the same, almost procedural, coding style is a workaround rather than an answer.

Comment: @Chaffers This algorithm fundamentally uses only a tiny fraction of the memory (only 2 rows) that maintaining the entire tableau costs (number of items + 1 rows). It's not any more efficient either, it takes the same amount of work to get to the last entry in the law row (and then you need a not-insignificant branch and bound stage afterwards). It's purely about the memory. Try it.

Comment: @Harold You miss my point, slightly helping the memory efficiency does not cure the problem of coding style. You are proposing a solution which is effectively procedural to cure a problem which is itself caused by a procedural style. Maintaining an entire code base within one method is wrong no matter how clever the algorithm. There is no opportunity for the GC to clean out unreachable objects, which is the root cause of the OOME.

Comment: @Chaffers Ok, I missed your point. In fact I missed it again. Why don't you edit your answer (which, btw, I did not vote down, but I didn't understand it either) with a more concrete suggestion? Because it seems to be that you're suggesting either 1) moving the inner loop to its own method (which wouldn't make any difference whatsoever), or 2) abandoning DP and doing something else (what?)

Answer (score 0):

Use a recursive method to solve the problem. see http://penguin.ewu.edu/~trolfe/Knapsack01/Knapsack01.html for further information.

Hope it will be of help.

Answer (score -2):

Break your for loops down into method calls.

This will have the effect of making the local variables GC'able once the method itself has completed.

So instead of nested for loops within the same main method call a method with the same functionality, which then calls a second method and you are effectively breaking the code up into small packets of local variables which can be collected when out of scope.