# memory optimization of Unbounded knapsack algorithm

Tags: java, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

In the classic unbounded knapsack algorithm solution using Dynamic Programming (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Unbounded_knapsack_problem), we allocate an integer array of size of knapsack to store the max values.

If I have a knapsack with a 1 Billion size, how do I optimize the DP solution to make sure that I can accommodate the `int[] knapsack` array? Because the memory taken by Java for 1B sized knapsack = `10^9 * 4Bytes = 3.7GB` of memory alone.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20407221/dynamic-programming-with-large-inputs

Comment: It's not a question of optimizing the DP solution, it's a question of finding a completely different solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to solve this problem with all of the data in memory, you'll have to work out a solution that uses secondary memory such as accessing a file or possibly setup a database.

Comment: It's not impossible to allocate GBs of memory in a Java heap.
The issue here is that the largest single array in Java is limited to 2GB.
So use various BigArray helper classes on the web, or use an array of arrays or other collection classes.

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer Are you sure about the 2GB limit? Because I did new int[1000000000] and that works for me with an 8g heap.

Comment: 1,000,000,000 is not even 1 GB :)

Comment: The limitation is in the Java language specification, chapter 10.4: "Arrays must be indexed by int values; "

Comment: Sorry, bad english: the INDEX is limited by MAX_INTEGER ( minus some number)

Comment: the biggest single array I can create on my machine is `long[] bubu = new long[Integer.MAX_VALUE - 3];`